# Working vnc xstartup for 19.04?

Tags: vnc, gnome-session

Has anyone got a usable `xstartup` for out-of-the-box 19.04? This minimal version just produces a black screen:

```
#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
gnome-session&
```

I've found half-a-dozen others by searching, but none of them produces any output. I'm on tigervnc. Thanks.